# Postgres 9.5: Non-zero xmax of a row refenced as a foreign key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key-relationship

According to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html:

> xmax - The identity (transaction ID) of the deleting transaction, or
>   zero for an undeleted row version. It is possible for this column to
>   be nonzero in a visible row version. That usually indicates that the
>   deleting transaction hasn't committed yet, or that an attempted
>   deletion was rolled back.

But if a row is referenced as a foreign key by another row, it also has a non-zero value for xmax:

```
drop table if exists demo;
create table demo
(
    id bigint primary key not null,
    pid bigint,
    constraint demo_pid_fk
        foreign key (pid)
    references demo (id)
);

insert into demo(id, pid) values(1, NULL); 
insert into demo(id, pid) values(2, 1); 
insert into demo(id, pid) values(3, 3); 
select xmin, xmax, * from demo;
 xmin | xmax | id | pid 
------+------+----+-----
 1074 | 1075 |  1 |    
 1075 |    0 |  2 |   1
 1076 | 1076 |  3 |   3
(3 rows)

insert into demo(id, pid) values(4, 1); 
select xmin, xmax, * from demo;
 xmin | xmax | id | pid 
------+------+----+-----
 1074 | 1077 |  1 |    
 1075 |    0 |  2 |   1
 1076 | 1076 |  3 |   3
 1077 |    0 |  4 |   1
(4 rows)
```

In the example above, it seems that xmax is set to the id of a last transaction that referenced the row as a foreign key. Why is it so? How does Postgres know that the row is still alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a talk by Bruce Momkian on [MVCC, unveiling xmin and xmax work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sq_aO34SWZc) ([slides](https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/mvcc.pdf), search for "Row Locks Using Xmax").

Long story short: `xmax` also used — not well covered in docs — for row locks, and in this specific case `xmax` is used to ensure other transactions will stay away from modifying referenced tuple (so `CASCADE` will wait, for example), unless `txid_current()` is bigger than `xmax` of your insert. Effectively, those nonzero xmaxes in your table are no use and cleaned up by `VACUUM FULL demo`.